# Why does multiprocessing not speed up my code

Tags: python, optimization, multiprocessing

I was trying to test the extent to which multiprocessing could speed up code, so I did this:

```
rom pathos.multiprocessing import Pool
def wm():
    l = []
    for i in range(1000):
        for j in range(1000):
            l.append(i+j)
    return l

def m():
    with Pool() as pool:
        return pool.starmap(lambda x, y: x+y, ((i, j) for j in range(1000) for i in range(1000)))
```

```
%%timeit
wm()
79.1 ms ± 1.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
m()
11.8 s ± 5.12 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It seems like multiprocessing is not making my code faster, but significantly slower. While it was running I also checked task manager and the cpu readings were quite low...

PS: I used pathos.multiprocessing cause the normal multiprocessing had some pickle error and it was suggested to use pathos.multiprocessing from another SO question.

Comment: A question to help with intuition here: what do you think is faster: a) adding two numbers, or b) transferring those two numbers to a separate process, adding them, and then returning the result to the original process?

Comment: @Brian Also startup and teardown of those other processes, serialization of the numbers and functions, etc.

Comment: Does this mean that if I try a more complicated process multiprocessing should be faster?

Comment: It's almost impossible to come up with a general rule.  Multiprocessing can help if you have a well-defined set of processing that needs to be done on multiple data structures, and can be done independently on those structures, but the processing needs to be significant enough to overcome the overhead of process startup and the cost of transferring the data back and forth.

Comment: Not only inter-process communication is slow, but CPython use pickle to transfer data between processes. One process need to pickle data and the other need to unpickle it. This serialization/deserialization is far more expensive than `append` and doing `i+j`. Besides multithreading is not very useful here due to the GIL. This is a very common issue with Python and more specifically the CPython interpreter.